# Apache Drill 1.2 and Oracle JDBC

Tags: jdbc, oracle10g, rdbms, apache-drill

Using Apache Drill v1.2 and  Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit in embedded mode.

I'm curious if anyone has had any success connecting Apache Drill to an Oracle DB. I've updated the `drill-override.conf` with the following configurations (per documents):

```
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "drillbits1",
  zk.connect: "localhost:2181",
  drill.exec.sys.store.provider.local.path = "/mypath"
}
```

and placed the `ojdbc6.jar` in `\apache-drill-1.2.0\jars\3rdparty`. I can successfully create the storage plug-in:

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
  "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP>:<PORT>:<SID>",
  "username": "USERNAME",
  "password": "PASSWORD",
  "enabled": true
}
```

but when I issue a query such as:

```
    select * from <storage_name>.<schema_name>.`dual`;
```

I get the following error:

```
Query Failed: An Error Occurred
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION ERROR: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 20: Table '<storage_name>.<schema_name>.dual' not found [Error Id: 57a4153c-6378-4026-b90c-9bb727e131ae on <computer_name>:<PORT>].
```

I've tried to query other schema/tables and get a similar result. I've also tried connecting to Teradata and get the same error. Does any one have suggestions/run into similar issues?

Comment: I don't know much about Oracle DB. Don't you think database name should also be there in query.

Comment: DB/SID is provided in the URL to the plug-in. I tried including it in the query but that doesn't change the result, and pulling it out of the storage plug-in leads to a creation error.

Comment: Have you tried  select * from <storage_name>.`dual`;  I got some duplicate key error like this one: http://www.scalerlabs.io/blog/apache-drill-exploring-connecting-to-rdbms-via-jdbc/

Comment: `use <storage_name>` and then `show tables` worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working with Drill 1.3 (released on 23-Dec-2015)

Plugin: name - **oracle**

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
  "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@192.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521:orcl ",
  "enabled": true
}
```

Query:

```
select * from <plugin-name>.<user-name>.<table-name>;
```

Example:

```
select * from oracle.USER.SAMPLE;
```

Check [drill's documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/rdbms-storage-plugin/#example-oracle-configuration) for more details.

> **Note**: Make sure you added `ojdbc7.12.1.0.2.jar`(recommended in docs) in `apache-drill-1.3.0/jars/3rdparty`

Comment: confirmed...the updates to 1.3 have fixed this issue

Comment: shot in the dark but have you tried any Teradata connections? It doesn't look to be actively tested and I've been unable to set up the storage plug-in.

Comment: @eroma934 Yes, it worked. I am sure u added `tdgssconfig.jar` and `terajdbc4.jar` in `jars/3rdparty`

Comment: @eroma934 You can add a new question with plugin details and all if not able to achieve this after adding these jars

Comment: Do we have to restart drillbit after placing the jars under 3rdparty?

Comment: @SrihariKaranth I didn't find anything in the docs regarding this. Sorry, I can't recall because I worked on it months ago.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of works in Apache drill 1.3.
The strange thing is that I can only query the tables for which there are synonyms created...
In the command line try:
use <storage_name>;
show tables;
This will give you a list of objects that you can query - dual is not on that list ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using apache-drill-1.9.0 and it seems that the schema name is interpreted case sensitive and must be be therefore be in upper case.

For a table  `user1.my_tab` (which is per default created in Oracle in upper case)
this works in Drill (plugin name is *oracle*)

```
SELECT * FROM oracle.USER1.my_tab;
```

But this triggers an error

```
SELECT * FROM oracle.user1.my_tab;

SEVERE: org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Table 'oracle.user1.my_tab' not found
```

An alternative approach is to set the plugin name and the schema name with `use`  (owner must be upper case as well)

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> use oracle.USER1;
+-------+-------------------------------------------+
|  ok   |                  summary                  |
+-------+-------------------------------------------+
| true  | Default schema changed to [oracle.USER1]  |
+-------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row selected (0,169 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select * from my_tab;
+------+
|  X   |
+------+
| 1.0  |
| 1.0  |
+------+
2 rows selected (0,151 seconds)
```