# apache-drill storage plugin creation failed

Tags: oracle, jdbc, rdbms, ojdbc, apache-drill

I was trying to create a storage plugin configuration in apache-drill ( 1.6 ) for oracle jdbc. I have already copied `ojdbc7.jar`  within the `apache-drill-1.6.0/jars/3rdparty`  directory.

But am getting an error

> Please retry: error (unable to create/ update storage)

while trying to create the storage plugin !

Here is the storage plugin configuration:

```
   {
      "type": "jdbc",
      "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
      "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@xx.xx.xx.xx:1521:***",
      "enabled": true
    }
```

& here is the `drill-override.conf` file :

```
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "drillbits1",
  zk.connect: "localhost:2181",
  sys.store.provider.local.path="/data/drill"
}
```

I have restarted drill after copying ojdbc7.jar file within the drill 3rd party directory !

I found some similar issues here in stackoverflow .. ( [storage_plugin failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291340/cant-create-drill-storage-plugin-for-oracle) & [drill-1.3&Oracle jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351412/apache-drill-1-2-and-oracle-jdbc) ) But nothing worked for me !!

Do you have any idea about this ?

[ I am using apache-drill version 1.6 in distributed mode ,  centOS 7 & java_version 1.8 ]

Comment: I am sure you must have verified your credentials and your password doesn't contains **@**. Did you find anything in logs?

Comment: I have verified the login credentials... password doesn't contain '@'. I have tried to connect using the oracle SQL developer using the same details & it worked ! No more errors are showing in drill log files also ! :( Is there anything with the drill version ? I recently switched into drill 1.6  [ Initially I was using drill 1.4 & I was able to create configuration plugins there without much problems ]

Comment: @devツ : I forgot to mention one thing ! I am doing this in a cloud server ( Microsoft Azure ) . So , do I have to open any port for this storage plugin creation purpose ? So far, I have opened ports **2181** (both inbound & outbound ), **5433** ( for jdbc driver - both inbound & outbound ) part from the ports for basic usage ! Do I have to open any other ports for establishing the connection between drill-server & oracle db ?

Comment: I don't have any experience with cloud server Arun. But [here](https://drill.apache.org/docs/ports-used-by-drill/) is the detail about ports used by Drill.

Comment: @devツ : What if the oracle db's time zone is different from the timezone of the server in which apache-drill is running ? Do you have any idea about this ? I just created a java code to connect to the same oracle db using the same credentials that I have mentioned in the question. This code failed when I ran this for the first time, by throwing an error : **ORA-01882: timezone region not found** . Then I added these two lines in my code - `TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone);` , then it started working & I was able to connect to the DB.

Comment: Drill does not provide any configuration (like Timezone) for RDBMS. You have to change it from Oracle end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by myself. Here is the changes that I did to resolve this one :

1. I changed my storage plugin configuration  ( according to this [POST](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-3992) )

   ```
   {    
     "type": "jdbc", 
     "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
     "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP>:<PORT>:<SID>", 
     "username": "<USERNAME>", 
     "password": "<PASSWORD>",
     "enabled": true
   }
   ```
2. Just changed drill-override.conf

   ```
   drill.exec: {
      cluster-id: "drillbits1",
      zk.connect: "localhost:2181",
     drill.exec.sys.store.provider.local.path="/data/drill"
   }
   ```

3 . Also, I replaced ojdbc7.jar with ojdbc6.jar ( I was trying to connect oracle DB version. 11.2.0.4 -